# How to generate standard normal in R

Tags: probability, statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a few questions that I need some explanations/clarity for:

Two methods for generating a standard normal are:

1. Take the sum of 3 uniform random numbers and scale to have mean 0 and sd = 1. (use properties of the uniform distribution and mean to determine the required transformation).
2. Generate a standard uniform and then apply inverse cdf function to obtain a random variate. For each method generate 10000 random numbers and check the distribution using.

For both methods produce:

(a) Normal probability plot

(b) Mean and standard deviation

(c) The proportion of the data lying within the theoretical 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles and
the 0.5 and 99.5 percentiles.

My understanding of the first question:

> 1. Take the sum of 3 uniform random numbers and scale to have mean 0 and
>      sd = 1. (use properties of the uniform distribution and mean to
>      determine the required transformation).

Is that I must create a normal distribution by taking the sum of 3 random numbers with a mean of 0 and sd = 1? 
To do this I used `rnorm(3,mean=0,sd=1)` in R. I am unsure of what it means by: (use properties of the uniform distribution and mean to determine the required transformation).

Could someone try to explain what this question means exactly? or link a resource that I can read that will help me understand?

> 2. Generate a standard uniform and then apply inverse cdf function to obtain a random variate. For each method generate 10000 random numbers and check the distribution using.

To generate a standard uniform, I used R's runif(10000) function, then I believe I should use pnorm somehow to obtain the normal random variate? 
I am a little confused at this question, do I need to find the sd and mean of my newly generated distribution and then input it into pnorm()? What exactly is a normal random variate in this case?

Sorry for all the questions, I am extremely confused and I'm just trying to wrap my head around what a lot of this stuff actually means, I've tried googling a bulk of it but I still don't understand.

Comment: I believe that for #1 it is saying to approximate a normal r.v. using the sum of three UNIFORM r.v., scaled to have sd=1. In R, you draw uniform r.v. using the function $\texttt{runif}$. You’ll have to use knowledge of a uniform distribution to understand what the sampling distribution of the sum of three uniform r.v. is, and how to scale that to have sd =1.

Comment: "inverse cdf function" would be `qnorm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly an exercise about properties of distributions.
Neither method of generating normal data makes practical sense.

- (1) Sum of *three* independent uniform random variables is
  is not enough. Better to sum 12 of them and subtract 6, which
  gives a better fit to normal and avoids the need for scaling. [See [Wikipedia on Irwin-Hall distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).]
- (2) If you're going to use the normal quantile function (inverse CDF) to convert standard uniform distributions to normal. That will work perfectly, but as a practical matter, why use `qnorm(runif(10))`
  when you can use R to get 10 standard uniform random variables
  with `rnorm(10)`?

**Trying to simulate a standard normal RV by adding three uniform RVs.** A little help with (1): A standard uniform random variable $U_1$ has 
$E(U_1) = 1/2, Var(U_1) = 1/12.$ So the total $T$ of three
has $E(T) = 3/2, Var(T) = 3/12 = 1/4, SD(T) = 1/2.$
Then $Z = 2(T - 3/2)$ has $E(Z) = 0; SD(Z) = 1.$

You can't make a normal probability plot in (1) without
having a *sample* of several. Instructions for (2) suggests $n=10,000,$ so let's go with that.  Here is a sample of $n$
of the transformed $Z_i$ from above.

```
set.seed(601)
z = replicate( 10^4, 2*( sum(runif(3)) - 3/2) ) )
qqnorm(z)
```

[image]

The normal probability plot is distinctly nonlinear.
Also, you can tell something is wrong because values of $Z$ are
all contained in $(-3,3),$ which is certainly not true
of standard uniform random variables.

Here is a histogram of the simulated $Z$s along with the
standard normal density curve. The fit is not so good.

```
hist(z, prob=T, br=30, ylim=c(0,.4), xlim=c(-5,5),
```

col="skyblue2", 
         main="Histogram of Poorly Simulated Std Normal Obs")
     curve(dnorm(x), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)

[image]

A formal Shapiro-Wilk test detects that the $Z$s aren't normal
rejecting the null hypothesis of normality with a tiny P-value.
[This procedure will accommodate only samples of size 5000 or
smaller, so I used just that many.]

```
mean(z); sd(z)
[1] -0.0139775  # aprx 0
[1] 0.9998204   # aprx 1
```

Mean and SD of the sample of $n = 10,000$ observations are
very close to 0 and 1, respectively. With $10,000$ observations
you can expect about 1 decimal place of accuracy. Our transformation from $T$ to $Z$ did what it was supposed to do.

```
mean(z > -1.96 & z < 1.96)
[1] 0.9533
```

A little more than 95% of the $Z$s fall in the interval
$(-1.96, 1.96).$ Remember that the distribution of the $Z$s
is short-tailed compared with standard normal. [In R,
`z > -1.96 & z < 1.96` is a logical vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s;
its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s. Also, the symbol `&` stands for intersection.]

I will leave the rest of (1) and all of (2) for you to finish.
[I don't this you're supposed to use `rnorm` for this problem,
but to explore ways of getting a normal sample without using
this obvious procedure.]

---

*Notes:* (1) There is no closed form for a normal CDF. However,
for computer use Michael Wichura found a piecewise rational approximation to it, and also inverted it to get a rational approximation to the normal quantile function. Both are accurate
up to double precision arithmetic. [R uses Wichura's approximations](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/Normal.html) for its procedures `pnorm` and `qnorm`.

(2) In the early days of computation when almost all operations
other than plain arithmetic were expensive, it was common
practice to sample from the standard uniform distribution by
adding 12 standard uniform variates (from a pseudoranom number generator) and subtracting 6. Not sufficiently precise for
modern simulation, but served well into the 1960s.

```
set.seed(1776)
z.1 = replicate(5000, sum(runif(12)) - 6)
summary(z.1);  sd(z.1)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-3.700735 -0.684320 -0.007370  0.008143  0.685387  3.367922 
[1] 1.003538            # SD aprx 1;  mean aprx 0
shapiro.test(z.1)$p.val
[1] 0.2850659           # Passes Shapiro test, large P-value
```